# Trying to export all permissions in a share using NTFSSecurity powershell module

Tags: powershell, permissions, ntfs

Hi I'm attempting to export file share permissions but as is typical the file path length for a lot of our shares exceeds 260 characters.

From what I can tell the NTFSSecurity module (https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/NTFSSecurity/4.2.4) should work past 260 character length but I don't think it's working correctly due to dir not supporting past 260 character length.

Any assistance that can get the below working with the module is appreciated.

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable 

Import-module -name NTFSSecurity   

set-location -path D:\Shares\

Dir -dir -recurse | Get-ntfsaccess |export-csv c:\temp\test.csv
```

Comment: You can enable long file name support in Win10 onwards: https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-10/enable-long-file-name-support-windows-10. Additonally if you map a drive further down the share e.g. d:\shares\folder\folder to shorten the path it will work.

Comment: Yea we have a lot of clients on older systems etc the mapping is alright when we want to copy items etc but I want to be able to create full reports in a way where I'm not having to spend like 2 hours pre-mapping drives etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna get fancy the below is a much better version prompts to enter path instead of altering the script and the policy setting at the end now waits for a Y/N input to set it instead of setting it the second it's done with the other part of the script.

$path = Read-Host "Please enter path"

$policy = get-executionpolicy

Set-executionpolicy bypass

Get-Module -ListAvailable

Import-module -name NTFSSecurity

Get-ChildItem2 -Path $Path -Recurse -Directory| Get-ntfsaccess |export-csv c:\temp\fileshareoutput.csv

$msg = 'has the file stopped growing? [Y/N]'

do {

```
$response = Read-Host -Prompt $msg 

if ($response -eq 'y') {
```

Set-executionpolicy $policy

write-host 'policy set to'

write-host $policy

```
}
```

} until ($response -eq 'n')